# How can I prevent that bots are generating costs at my AWS Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, security, aws-lambda, bots

I was planning a concept for my mobile Game and using AWS Lambda (or Firebase Functions where its the same). Couldn't a bot permanently do a request to my Lambda-Function and generate massive costs by only spamming my Endpoint?

Is there any protection from Amazon / Google or how would you guys secure you Endpoint for this kind of attacks?

Comment: please take a look at WAF (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-aws-waf.html)

Comment: I would personally put CloudFlare in front of the API, block all calls to the API that aren't from CloudFlare, and use CloudFlare's bot protection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Protecting API Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-best-practices-ddos-resiliency/protecting-api-endpoints-bp4.html), and more generally read [AWS Best Practices for DDoS Resiliency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-best-practices-ddos-resiliency/welcome.html).

You would use a combination of:

- API Gateway (with authenticated clients and, potentially, throttling)
- CloudFront
- WAF